# Facing issue in publishing product in API Connect CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect, apic

While executing

```
apic products publish climb-on.yaml --server mgmnthost.com --org climbon --catalog sandbox
```

i am getting

> You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this operation.

I executed `apic orgs --server mgmnthost.com`

but, i am getting nothing with this command.

Might be i am using an incorrect organization name (fetched the name from **catalog identifier** string.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks. Aman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make sure that you have:

- Logged in, using the same server you are trying to publish to:

  apic login --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD --server ${APIC_SERVER}
- The user needs to have publisher permissions in that organization, in the specific catalog you are trying to publish the product to (Product Manager is the default role name for that)

Comment: :Thank for sharing this. It seems to be an issue with the publisher permissions i have in that organization. I will update with the appropriate role here, shortly)

Comment: I had all the roles specified in the portal. Just that my id had been added by providing the mail-id instead of the unique id within my organization. After re-adding the user with the unique id(specific to the firm), i am able to publish api through CLI.